# How to mount the metadata template to certain device of Apache IoTDB?

Tags: database, time-series, apache-iotdb, iotdb

Does Apache IoTDB have an interface to create `device` nodes? If it cannot be created independently of the time series, I wonder how to mount the metadata template to certain `device` node? Since I understand that the application of the metadata template in IoTDB should be mounted on the path of a certain device.

Answer (score 1):

Metadata templates of Apache IoTDB are generally applied to a type of devices, and the measurement points of this type of devices are the same. After the template is created, you can directly mount the template to a path node using command like `set schema template t1 to root.db.device_class_A`. This path node does not need to be created in advance. All devices below the layer the template is mounted to will use this template. Therefore, there is no need to mount the template separately for devices one by one.